# Image upload, resolution check, crop and preview. PHP

Tags: php, jquery, upload, preview

I am looking for a solution to upload an image, check the resolution crop it if necessary then then preview the image before it then gets printed onto a canvas.

I have found loads of examples of this but obviously nothing straight forward, plus i don't want to rip off someone elses work.

ASP is NOT an option as the site uses PHP and is on a 'nix box.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the file will need to be POSTed to your PHP script. You can do this with HTML forms(`input type='file'`) or [jQuery background uploaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery). Uploads are stored by default in the temporary directory of your web server, the current directory can be found by looking at the output of `phpinfo()`.

Next check out the [$_FILES](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) global specifically [move_uploaded_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), you can find the image type from the `type` key in the $_FILES array, though that can be manipulated client side it it might be better to check the file type manually [using magic byte functions](http://pastebin.com/pW6z1eW9).

Once you have the file uploaded then you need to manipulate it. You can use either [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), ImageMagick may not be built-in to your PHP version, GD is pretty common. I am more familar with GD, so I'll suggest you check out the functions [imagecreatefromjpeg()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php)/png/gif & [imagecopyresampled()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php), which can both crop and resample. To find out if you need to crop / resize you can check the aspect ratio. Here's a function I whipped up:

```
function fixRatio($x, $y, $ratio) {
    $ratio = round($ratio,6);
    $iRatio = round($x / $y, 6);
    if ($iRatio > $ratio) {
        $x = ceil($y * $ratio);
    } else if ($iRatio < $ratio) {
        $y = ceil($x * (1 / $ratio));
    }
    return array('x' => $x, 'y' => $y);
}
```

You input the width, height & desired aspect ratio & this will spit out an array that contains the corrected dimensions. It's probably best to specify the ratio by dividing desired height by desired width, e.g. `fixRatio($x, $y, 640/480)`. You can then use that info to crop the image w/ `imagecopyresampled()`, at the same time you can specify to the function the destination width & height. So if everything must be 640x480, then you would specify that when calling `imagecopyresampled()`. You can then use [iamgejpeg()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)/gif/png to output the image as a file to a public directory on your server. Since it's public you can reference it via a URL be it an HTML form asking the user to confirm if they like what they see or [into a canvas element](http://www.phpied.com/photo-canvas-tag-flip/).